# Adding 3D Touch Quick Actions to a Safari home screen shortcut?

Tags: ios, mobile-safari, iphone-standalone-web-app, quickaction, 3dtouch

With the introduction of the iPhone 6s, 3D Touch was announced. With that, came a new feature called [Quick Actions](http://www.apple.com/iphone-6s/3d-touch/). These allow you to access 1-4 actions quickly for an app on your home screen, simply by 3D Touching it.

For example, the Maps app provides these 4 shortcuts:

[image]

If the user adds my webpage to their home screen via Safari, is there an API for me to specify which Quick Actions will appear when they press on the icon? (Currently when they 3D touch on the icon, it does nothing.)

What if my webpage is [`apple-web-app-mobile-capable`](https://developer.apple.com/library/safari/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariHTMLRef/Articles/MetaTags.html)--meaning it runs as a standalone app--will that allow me to provide quick actions?

Comment: Do you want to add custom quick actions to the Safari app?

Comment: @grane2212 No, I want to add custom quick actions to my webpage that is on the user's home screen.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this?